# PHP: check for null values with null before the variable

Tags: php, null

I know this could seem a silly question, but I saw many times checking a **null value** this way:

```
$var = null;

if (null !== $var) { 
    // do something
}
```

and not, like

```
$var !== null
```

The result is the same I guess, but why the null before the variabile?
Maybe it's a sugar way to write code, or it is functional for something indeed?

Thanks for those who want to answer :)

Comment: It's just a convention to make sure that you do not accidentally assign that variable to null.

Comment: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)